# Why does my input always display none in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a quiz to be used in a primary school environment however I am having an issue with some of the code that I have used. I am trying to get the answer to be input beside the displayed question however the keyword `None` is displayed on the next line and my input is forced to there. I am not defining any functions so I am unable to incorporate a `return` function anywhere. My input code, at the moment, looks like this:

```
    answer_user = input(print("\n", a, c, b, ":"))
```

Comment: Please narrow this down to the code relevant to the problem.

Comment: I guess `print`returns `None`

Comment: It may, however I am not aware of any alternative to displaying the question.

Comment: Just give the string as an argument.  `input()` will print it for you.  See below answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` returns `None`, so if it given as an argument to `input`, `input` prints `None` in addition to what `print` prints.

```
answer_user = input("\n%s %s %s:" % (a, c, b))
```

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed the issue and I was aware of  '=+' as opposed to my earlier method however I had an issue with that so I went back to the basics. This works exactly how i would have liked it to

Answer (score 1):

I've not understood your question clearly. But I think the fault lies in this line `answer_user = input(print("\n", a, c, b, ":"))`.

Simply change it to:

```
answer_user = input("\n {} {} {} :".format(a, c, b))
```